# Gaining access to PHPMyAdmin in Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin

I recently installed Laravel on my server and now I can no longer access PHPMyAdmin since Laravel thinks the path doesn't exists, how can I create a path that still refers to phpmyadmin?

It shouldn't be to hard but I can't seem to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Laravel should ignore all paths that point to physical files. Is PHPMyAdmin in your public directory?

Comment: @fubar in my `etc` folder?

Comment: Are you trying to use PHPMyAdmin on the same domain as Laravel? Perhaps you can post your directory structure, where Laravel is installed and where PHPMyAdmin is installed to speed this up.

Comment: @fubar Yeah, I had phpmyadmin installed on my previous page but then I later installed laravel on the same vps, now it won't load, I don't really know where everything is installed tbh. I just followed some tutorials, I'm a total nobhead when it comes to a computersystem. I just know that after I installed laravel it would just give me a Laravel 404 error.

Comment: Okay. I'm sorry, but if you can't provide more information as to where things are installed in your webroot, I can't help. Good luck.